# Select axes DFT of multi-dimensional array (using FFTW)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fftw

I have data that is ordered as follows

```
[ z, y, x, i, j ]
```

where `[z,y,x]` represent *physical dimensions* and `[i,j]` represent *tensor dimensions*. I.e. it stores a second-order tensor at points in grid with shape `[z,y,x]`.

I would like to calculate the Fourier transform of each tensor component `[i,j]` along the physical dimensions `[z,y,x]`, **using FFTW in C**.

The NumPy-equivalent of this operation would be

```
np.fft.fftn(a, axes=(0, 1, 2))
```

Neither the documentation nor Google have provided the answer.

Comment: The [Guru interface of FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Guru-Interface.html#Guru-Interface) can prove useful in such cases. I like the advice on the documentation page: `For those users who require the flexibility of the guru interface, it is important that they pay special attention to the documentation lest they shoot themselves in the foot. `